# Generating recursive class instances from an array of splitted values by dashes (as a folder tree)

Tags: c#, recursion, memory-optimization

Well, I'm trying to generate the following:

**Input:**

```
Level1a/Level2a/Level3a/Level4a
Level1a/Level2a/Level3a/Level4b
Level1a/Level2a/Level3a/Level4c
Level1a/Level2a/Level3b/Level4a
Level1a/Level2a/Level3b/Level4b
Level1a/Level2a/Level3b/Level4c
Level1a/Level2a/Level3c/Level4a
Level1a/Level2a/Level3c/Level4b
Level1a/Level2a/Level3c/Level4c
Level1a/Level2b/Level3a/Level4a
Level1a/Level2b/Level3a/Level4b
Level1a/Level2b/Level3a/Level4c
Level1a/Level2b/Level3b/Level4a
Level1a/Level2b/Level3b/Level4b
Level1a/Level2b/Level3b/Level4c
Level1a/Level2b/Level3c/Level4a
Level1a/Level2b/Level3c/Level4b
Level1a/Level2b/Level3c/Level4c
Level1a/Level2c/Level3a/Level4a
Level1a/Level2c/Level3a/Level4b
Level1a/Level2c/Level3a/Level4c
Level1a/Level2c/Level3b/Level4a
Level1a/Level2c/Level3b/Level4b
Level1a/Level2c/Level3b/Level4c
Level1a/Level2c/Level3c/Level4a
Level1a/Level2c/Level3c/Level4b
Level1a/Level2c/Level3c/Level4c
Level1b/Level2a/Level3a/Level4a
Level1b/Level2a/Level3a/Level4b
Level1b/Level2a/Level3a/Level4c
Level1b/Level2a/Level3b/Level4a
Level1b/Level2a/Level3b/Level4b
Level1b/Level2a/Level3b/Level4c
Level1b/Level2a/Level3c/Level4a
Level1b/Level2a/Level3c/Level4b
Level1b/Level2a/Level3c/Level4c
Level1b/Level2b/Level3a/Level4a
Level1b/Level2b/Level3a/Level4b
Level1b/Level2b/Level3a/Level4c
Level1b/Level2b/Level3b/Level4a
Level1b/Level2b/Level3b/Level4b
Level1b/Level2b/Level3b/Level4c
Level1b/Level2b/Level3c/Level4a
Level1b/Level2b/Level3c/Level4b
Level1b/Level2b/Level3c/Level4c
Level1b/Level2c/Level3a/Level4a
Level1b/Level2c/Level3a/Level4b
Level1b/Level2c/Level3a/Level4c
Level1b/Level2c/Level3b/Level4a
Level1b/Level2c/Level3b/Level4b
Level1b/Level2c/Level3b/Level4c
Level1b/Level2c/Level3c/Level4a
Level1b/Level2c/Level3c/Level4b
Level1b/Level2c/Level3c/Level4c
Level1c/Level2a/Level3a/Level4a
Level1c/Level2a/Level3a/Level4b
Level1c/Level2a/Level3a/Level4c
Level1c/Level2a/Level3b/Level4a
Level1c/Level2a/Level3b/Level4b
Level1c/Level2a/Level3b/Level4c
Level1c/Level2a/Level3c/Level4a
Level1c/Level2a/Level3c/Level4b
Level1c/Level2a/Level3c/Level4c
Level1c/Level2b/Level3a/Level4a
Level1c/Level2b/Level3a/Level4b
Level1c/Level2b/Level3a/Level4c
Level1c/Level2b/Level3b/Level4a
Level1c/Level2b/Level3b/Level4b
Level1c/Level2b/Level3b/Level4c
Level1c/Level2b/Level3c/Level4a
Level1c/Level2b/Level3c/Level4b
Level1c/Level2b/Level3c/Level4c
Level1c/Level2c/Level3a/Level4a
Level1c/Level2c/Level3a/Level4b
Level1c/Level2c/Level3a/Level4c
Level1c/Level2c/Level3b/Level4a
Level1c/Level2c/Level3b/Level4b
Level1c/Level2c/Level3b/Level4c
Level1c/Level2c/Level3c/Level4a
Level1c/Level2c/Level3c/Level4b
Level1c/Level2c/Level3c/Level4c
```

**Output:**

```
public static class Level1a
{
    public static class Level2a
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1488761881";
            public static string Level4b = "193501299";
            public static string Level4c = "1176619638";    
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1399332350";
            public static string Level4b = "2052111229";
            public static string Level4c = "890332317";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1532225081";
            public static string Level4b = "573356654";
            public static string Level4c = "2062588997";    
        }    
    }

    public static class Level2b
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1529741837";
            public static string Level4b = "222585494";
            public static string Level4c = "891285919";   
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "390696166";
            public static string Level4b = "594192298";
            public static string Level4c = "1083220943";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "702598359";
            public static string Level4b = "722402607";
            public static string Level4c = "1405833999";    
        }    
    }

    public static class Level2c
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "2048595403";
            public static string Level4b = "58370073";
            public static string Level4c = "524601020";    
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "980100293";
            public static string Level4b = "207581761";
            public static string Level4c = "1504264127";   
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1572666752";
            public static string Level4b = "643931200";
            public static string Level4c = "1591869757";    
        }    
    }  
}

public static class Level1b
{
    public static class Level2a
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "347647206";
            public static string Level4b = "1229370062";
            public static string Level4c = "2009415733";    
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1676726159";
            public static string Level4b = "1215950520";
            public static string Level4c = "524327104";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1167245618";
            public static string Level4b = "1439144914";
            public static string Level4c = "132046132";    
        }       
    }

    public static class Level2b
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "226999070";
            public static string Level4b = "1279391946";
            public static string Level4c = "192015774";    
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1312893735";
            public static string Level4b = "1056858701";
            public static string Level4c = "1619871324";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "167695140";
            public static string Level4b = "1184979870";
            public static string Level4c = "802335777";    
        }   
    }

    public static class Level2c
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "620553654";
            public static string Level4b = "539272091";
            public static string Level4c = "877305211";   
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "868125815";
            public static string Level4b = "687971845";
            public static string Level4c = "1271690402";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "2002666349";
            public static string Level4b = "543891764";
            public static string Level4c = "531171485";   
        }   
    }   
}

public static class Level1c
{
    public static class Level2a
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1037815829";
            public static string Level4b = "508661588";
            public static string Level4c = "2133403185";   
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1819839158";
            public static string Level4b = "1974149245";
            public static string Level4c = "1408180029";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1445946207";
            public static string Level4b = "1184577875";
            public static string Level4c = "1491470239";   
        }    
    }

    public static class Level2b
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "53173264";
            public static string Level4b = "2000499325";
            public static string Level4c = "1154118621";   
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "366958815";
            public static string Level4b = "1370934195";
            public static string Level4c = "1302531031";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "951174811";
            public static string Level4b = "475599289";
            public static string Level4c = "1590494308";    
        }    
    }

    public static class Level2c
    {
        public static class Level3a
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1213818225";
            public static string Level4b = "735701668";
            public static string Level4c = "1148995019";    
        }

        public static class Level3b
        {
            public static string Level4a = "1052213343";
            public static string Level4b = "812405153";
            public static string Level4c = "1170085538";    
        }

        public static class Level3c
        {
            public static string Level4a = "701928350";
            public static string Level4b = "952113098";
            public static string Level4c = "104659109";    
        }        
    }        
}
```

Actually, it works (as the rules marks), but I need to optimize it.

I'm using the following fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhtHbe

And to generate this actually uses almost 10Mb of RAM...

This is my code (you can use my *Fiddle* to experiment):

```
const bool debug = false;
private static IEnumerable<RecursiveNode> RecursiveSplitting(IEnumerable<string> arrs, string currentParent = "", string splitChar = "/", bool nestedDebug = false)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Separator))
        splitChar = Separator;

    UsedSeparator = splitChar;

    var _arrs = debug && !nestedDebug ? arrs.Where(a => a.Contains("Comix/")) : arrs;

    if(debug)
        nestedDebug = true;

    // bool wasFirstIteration = false;
    /*if(firstIteration) {
        wasFirstIteration = true;
        firstIteration = false;
    }*/

    string lastHandle = "";
    foreach (var item in _arrs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            // yield break;
            continue;

        string parent = string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentParent) && item.Contains(splitChar) ? item.Substring(0, item.LastIndexOf(splitChar)) : currentParent;

        if(!item.Contains(splitChar)) {
            yield return new RecursiveNode(item, parent);
            // yield break;
            continue;

            // throw new Exception("Nothing to split!");
        }

        var splitted = item.Split(splitChar.ToCharArray());

        if (lastHandle == splitted[0])
            // yield break;
            continue;

        lastHandle = splitted[0];

        var node = new RecursiveNode(lastHandle, parent);

        var subItems = arrs.Where(i => i.StartsWith(splitted[0] + splitChar) && i.Contains(splitChar))
                           .Select(i => i.Replace(splitted[0] + splitChar, string.Empty));

        // if(debug)
            Console.WriteLine("[Item={0}, SubItem Count={1}]", item, subItems.Count());

        // if(subItems.Count() == 0)
        //  continue;

        // Console.WriteLine(subItems.Count());

        if (splitted.Length == 1)
        {
            yield return new RecursiveNode(splitted[0], parent);
            // yield break;
            continue;
        }

        var subNodes = RecursiveSplitting(subItems, parent, splitChar, nestedDebug);
        node.Childs.AddRange(subNodes);

        yield return node;
    }
}

private static string OutputRecursiveNode(IEnumerable<RecursiveNode> nodes, Func<string, string> getFieldValue, int count = -1)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    ++count;

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        string indenter = new string('\t', count);

        var @class = indenter + GenerateClass(node.Value).Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + indenter);

        if (node.Childs.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(@class);
            sb.AppendLine(OutputRecursiveNode(node.Childs, getFieldValue, count));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@class))
                sb.AppendLine(indenter + "}");

            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        else
        {
            string field = GenerateField(node.Value, getFieldValue(node.CurrentParent + UsedSeparator + node.Value));
            sb.AppendLine(indenter + field);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static string GenerateClass(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return string.Empty;

    return string.Format("public static class {0}{1}{{", name, Environment.NewLine);
    // return $@"public static class {name}{Environment.NewLine}{{";
}

private static string GenerateField(string name, string fieldValue) // , Func<string> str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return string.Empty;

    return string.Format(@"public static string {0} = ""{1}"";", name, fieldValue);
}
```

Please, to experiment with the fiddle change the following part:

```
Console.WriteLine(LevelTest.CreateLevelsOneLine());
Console.WriteLine(DebugClasses());

// Console.WriteLine(MapClasses(nameMapping));
```

To:

```
// Console.WriteLine(LevelTest.CreateLevelsOneLine());
// Console.WriteLine(DebugClasses());

Console.WriteLine(MapClasses(nameMapping));
```

This is my model class:

```
public class RecursiveNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string CurrentParent { get; set; }
    public List<RecursiveNode> Childs { get; set; }

    private RecursiveNode()
    {
        Childs = new List<RecursiveNode>();
    }

    public RecursiveNode(string value, string parent)
        : this()
    {
        Value = value;
        CurrentParent = parent;
    }
}
```

And I still don't know where can be my memory leak, because I don't materialize any of the `IEnumerable`s... Until I reach the `StringBuilder` part where I build the final string... (But if you test the other part, the Fiddle just stops due to a timeout and the last memory report is about 1.50Gb)

**Note:** The only part that I materialize everything is in `node.Childs.AddRange(subNodes);` but is this causing the issue?

**Note2:** I would like that any nice person that answer this question helps me guiding me with possible refactors to this methods... (As my last && first question)

Any help is welcome!

Comment: For class generation, consider using CodeDom (https://thuru.net/2015/01/22/generating-code-using-system-codedom/). T4 (https://books.google.be/books?id=wWyFCeTpruYC&pg=PT355&lpg=PT355&dq=T4+class+generation&source=bl&ots=49fnuLvhgZ&sig=ACfU3U1RJgOWsf5dnfUGFY3I-M_MQ_00Uw&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjivdfXh9TiAhUHJ1AKHYhuAxYQ6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=T4%20class%20generation&f=false) is also a good bootstrapper for generating code. And of course Roslyn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt808499.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know CodeDom, but I prefer to keep it simple. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps these APIs have better memory management than a StringBuilder. It could be something to try... I also notice you do alot of string concatenation using the '+'-operator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431909/string-concatenation-memory-usage-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6):

#### Lazy versus eager

> I don't materialize any of the IEnumerables

Perhaps you should, because you're enumerating them many times, throwing away work again and again:

- In `Main`, that `nameMapping.Count()` debug output enumerates `nameMapping`, calling `GetName(node.Texture.Source)` for every item.
- In `MapClasses`, there's a materializing `ToArray` call.
- In `GetFieldValue`, `mapping.FirstOrDefault` has to enumerate `mapping` until it finds the first match. Because `mapping` is that same lazy `nameMapping` sequence, this too ends up calling `GetName(node.Texture.Source)` many times. It doesn't help that `GetFieldValue` gets called a lot - very likely resulting in \$O(n^2)\$ performance.
- In `RecursiveSplitting`, you're enumerating the given sequence with a `foreach` loop. There's also a debug `Count()` call there, and you're appending several `Where` and `Select` calls to the given sequence, resulting in more work for deeper recursive calls.

Or, in other words:

```
var lazy = items.Select(DoExpensiveWork);   // Returns a select wrapper, cheap.
lazy.Count();                               // Enumerates, doing expensive work.
lazy.FirstOrDefault(AlwaysFalse);           // Enumerates again, repeating expensive work.
// DoExpensiveWork has been called twice for every item, but all the results have been thrown away.
// Enumerating 'lazy' will repeat that work.

// versus:

var eager = items.Select(DoExpensiveWork).ToArray();    // Materializes immediately, expensive.
eager.Count();                                          // No enumeration required, cheap.
eager.FirstOrDefault(AlwaysFalse);                      // Enumerates materialized results, cheap.
// DoExpensiveWork has been called once for every item, and the results are stored.
// Enumerating 'eager' simply returns those results without repeating any work.
```

#### Use the right data structure

Repeated `FirstOrDefault` calls, where the selector just compares a single property, are an indication that you should be using a lookup table or dictionary instead - those offer \$O(1)\$ lookup instead of \$O(n)\$. Linq's `ToLookup` and `ToDictionary` methods are useful here. Originally, your code took about 17 seconds on my system. With an `ILookup`, that got cut down to about 0.3 second. Memory consumption got similarly reduced.

Answer (score 2):

`OutputRecursiveNode()`

- You are sometimes using `var` where the concrete type it isn't quite obvious from the right-hand-side of the assignment. Sometimes you use the concrete type where the type is obvious from the right-hand-side of the assignment (`string indenter = new string('\t', count);`)
- Appending a concatenated string to a `StringBuilder` should better be done by using multiple `Append()`'s.
- the `var @class` is created for each node but is only needed if `node.Childs.Count > 0`.
- the `indenter`is created for each iteration of the loop which should be done outside of the loop.
- The `StringBuilder`'s `ApendXx()` methods provide a fluent implementation, meaning these methods are returning a `StringBuilder` which could be used as well.
- The `GenerateClass()` method adds a `Environment.NewLine` which is then replaced by `Environment.NewLine + indenter`. By simply returning `"public static class " + name` from that method we can then `Append()` new line, the `indenter` and the opening brace.
- The condition  `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@class)` can't never evaluate to `false`.

Implementing these points will lead to

```
private static string OutputRecursiveNode(IEnumerable<RecursiveNode> nodes, Func<string, string> getFieldValue, int count = -1)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    ++count;

    var indenter = new string('\t', count);
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {

        if (node.Childs.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(indenter)
                .AppendLine(GenerateClass(node.Value))
                .Append(indenter)
                .Append("{")
                .AppendLine(indenter)
                .Append(OutputRecursiveNode(node.Childs, getFieldValue, count))
                .Append(indenter)
                .AppendLine("}");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(indenter)
                .Append(GenerateField(node.Value, getFieldValue(node.CurrentParent + UsedSeparator + node.Value)));
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and the changed `GenerateClass()` would look like so

```
private static string GenerateClass(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return "public static class " + name;
}
```

which leads to the next problem. If the name of the class is either `null` or `Empty` returning `string.Empty` wouldn't produce correct code. It would be better to either throw an `tException` (in the `OutputRecursiveNode()` method) or omitting classes which names are `null` or `Empty` but because the same applies to the `GenerateField()` method you should throw an Exception.

Just placing

```
if (nodes.Any(n => string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.Value))) { throw new YourDesiredtException(); }
```

at the top of the `OutputRecursiveNode()` method will do the trick.